# Proving Uniform Convergence and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

By using an upper bound prove that $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty~\frac{x}{n^{4/5}(1+nx^2)}$
converges uniformly on R and is

x $\rightarrow$ $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty~\frac{x}{n^{0.6}(1+nx^2)}$ continuous at all points on R

Comment: What is that second series there and how does it relate to the first one?

Comment: Is the series $\frac{x}{n^{4/5}(1+nx^2)}$ or is it $\frac{x}{n^{4/5}}(1+nx^2)$?

Comment: Sorry just edited

Comment: I'm struggling to find the upper bound and for the second part I don't know how to use the first part to show it is or is not continuous

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $f_n$ be our odd continuous function.

the numerator of its  derivative is

$$nx^2+1-2nx^2=1-nx^2$$

$$\implies$$

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)|=f_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$$

$$=\frac{1}{2n^{\frac{13}{10}}}$$

for the first, and

$$\frac{1}{2n^{1.1}}$$ for the second.

the two series of functions converge normally and uniformly  at $\mathbb R$ since

$\frac{13}{10}>1$ and $1.1>1$.

the sum functions are therefore continuous at $\mathbb R$.

Comment: In the second part, does the fact that the series is uniformly continuous imply that the mapping is coninuous?

Comment: @OliverThompson All the $f_n$ are continuous at R and the convergence is uniform at R .the sum function is continuous at R

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\frac{x}{1+nx^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}$$

Therefore, we have $$\frac{x}{n^{4/5}(1+nx^2)}\le \frac{1}{2n^{13/10}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compute

$$M_n = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\,\left |\frac{x}{n^{.6}(1+nx^2)}\right|.$$

Is $\sum_n M_n < \infty?$